# TFS Extension - How to read TaskAttachment content

Tags: javascript, iis, typescript, tfs, http-status-code-401

I'm having trouble with reading the content of a "TaskAttachment" that I uploaded from one extension to another.

I'm using this code to get the "**TaskAttachment**", I'm getting it with the right name and URL, (Which I get have access to without nay authentication, e.g. from another clean browser)

```
var taskClient = DT_Client.getClient();
taskClient.getPlanAttachments(vsoContext.project.id, "build", build.orchestrationPlan.planId, "MyExtType").then((taskAttachments) => {
$.each(taskAttachments, (index, taskAttachment) => {
   if (taskAttachment._links && taskAttachment._links.self && taskAttachment._links.self.href) {
        var link = taskAttachment._links.self.href;
        var attachmentName = taskAttachment.name;
        var fileContent = readText(link);
```

...
And this javascript function to read the content
...

```
var readText = function readTextFile(file)
{
alert("file = " + file);
var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
{
    alert("rawFile.readyState = " + rawFile.readyState);
    alert("rawFile.status = " + rawFile.status);
    alert("rawFile.responseText = " + rawFile.responseText);

    if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
    {

        if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
        {
            var allText = rawFile.responseText;
            alert(allText);
            return allText;
        }
    }
}
rawFile.send(null);
return "Failed to get data..";
}
```

The problem is that I'm getting 401 error message :
"**IIS 7.5 Detailed Error - 401.2 - Unauthorized**"

How can I read this file content? Is there a better way to transfer data from a "Build Step Extension" to a "UI Extension" that present the data in the build summary page (new tab)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just managed to read the attachment data using the "**getAttachmentContent**" method:

I'm not sure why MS doesn't put any reference to this function in the tutorial, after long digging in the documentation \ Q&A I found it.

```
taskClient.getPlanAttachments(vsoContext.project.id, "build", build.orchestrationPlan.planId, "My_Attachment_Type").then((taskAttachments) => {

                     $.each(taskAttachments, (index, taskAttachment) => {

                         if (taskAttachment._links && taskAttachment._links.self && taskAttachment._links.self.href) {

                         var recId = taskAttachment.recordId;
                         var timelineId = taskAttachment.timelineId;

                         taskClient.getAttachmentContent(vsoContext.project.id, "build", build.orchestrationPlan.planId,timelineId,recId,"My_Attachment_Type",taskAttachment.name).then((attachementContent)=> {

                              function arrayBufferToString(buffer){
                                 var arr = new Uint8Array(buffer);
                                 var str = String.fromCharCode.apply(String, arr);
                                 return str;
                             }

                             var data = arrayBufferToString(attachementContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to "IIS 7.5 Detailed Error - 401.2 - Unauthorized" It's most likely due to directory permissions set in the file system.

Make sure Anonymous access is enabled on IIS -> Authentication.

Right click on it, then click on Edit, and choose a domain\username and password.